# How to replace V8 library for Chromium in OSX?

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, v8, chromium

I am modifying V8 JavaScript engine, and planning to replace the existing one with the modified V8 library for Chromium.
I was able to do in Ubuntu as the library file, libv8.so, was located at /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libs. All I had to do was finding the version of V8 compatible with the version of Chromium installed, downloading and modifying the source code of V8, and replacing the library file.
I searched the entire file system for "libv8.*", but couldn't find any in my mac. I don't want to build the entire Chromium which takes too much time and disk space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Chromium in Ubuntu is built with component build (http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/component-build), so the v8 component is built to `libv8.so` and can be replaced directly.

I guess your Chromium in mac does not use component build, all components are built into a single `Chromium Framework`,  so there is no `libv8.dylib` to be replaced.